# Python: Cannot add the ViewFlow app to the list of installed apps

Tags: python, django-viewflow

Could you you please help me to add the ViewFlow library (http://docs.viewflow.io/quick_start.html) to the the list of installed apps in Django?

I use Anaconda with Python. Django and ViewFlow have been already installed.

Comment: You can check the viewflow hello world sample - https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook/tree/master/viewflow_helloworld